# Double click event for not editable UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios

I have not editable UITextView. When I make double click on it i need to set backgroung colour for it. How can I do this? I think that didbeginediting event will not occure because this UITextView is not editable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `Tap Gesture` to achieve your describe functionality.

- **add Tap Gesture** in your **TextView** using underneath code.

  ```
  UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGestureObj = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(TapMethod:)];
  tapGestureObj.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
  [textViewObj addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureObj];
  ```
- `TapMethod`

  ```
  -(void)TapMethod:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture
  {
     //Set your logic on double tap of TextView...
  }
  ```

Comment: thanks, but your answer is not working for me, event TapMethod: is not occure

Comment: @revolutionkpi Did you set userinteraction for textview

Comment: You can set userinteraction = YES and editable = NO and also if your text view's parent view is imageview means you have to set userinteraction for that imageview also

Answer (score 1):

You can add tap gesture to the text view and you just set numberoftapsrequired = 2 then in gesture recognizer method you change the bg color  also set userInteractionEnabled = yes